# Parsing Date values

Tags: javascript

Right now my function is

```
    if(dateCheck("02.05.2013","17.09.2013","02.07.2013"))
    alert("Availed");
else
    alert("Not Availed");

function dateCheck(from,to,check) {

    var fDate,lDate,cDate;
    fDate = Date.parse(from);
    lDate = Date.parse(to);
    cDate = Date.parse(check);

    if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Always returning false, Getting dates in this format from the server side 02.09.2013
Please suggest right format for parsing these values?

Comment: use the `getTime()` method which returns the milliseconds in a Date. From there you can compare the milliseconds, higher milliseconds means more recent date

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It's already epoch values

Comment: Always returning false, Getting dates in this format from the server side "02.05.2013"

Comment: @KamleshBisht see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse your date to date object in `javascript`. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) can give you an idea of date constructor in `javascript`.It has a constructor `new Date(year,month,date)`. so parse your dateString in that format. follow the code

```js
if(dateCheck("02.05.2013","02.09.2013","02.07.2013"))
        alert("Availed");
    else
        alert("Not Availed");
    
    function dateCheck(from,to,check) {
    
        var fDate,lDate,cDate;
        fDate = new Date(from.split(".")[2],from.split(".")[1],from.split(".")[0]);
        
        lDate = new Date(to.split(".")[2],to.split(".")[1],to.split(".")[0]);
        cDate = new Date(check.split(".")[2],check.split(".")[1],check.split(".")[0]);
     
    
    
        if((cDate<= lDate) && (cDate >= fDate)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzwhz8hv/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like duplicate of [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).
Your date is not clear as 02.09. might be the second of September or the 9th of Feb. See the referenced post for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dateCheck("02/05/2013","02/09/2013","02/06/2013"))
    alert("Availed");
else
    alert("Not Availed");

function dateCheck(from,to,check) {

    var fDate,lDate,cDate;

    fDate = convertDate(from);
    lDate = convertDate(to);
    cDate = convertDate(check);

    if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


function convertDate(dateStr) {
    var parts = dateStr.split("/");
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[0], parts[1] - 1);
}
```

Comment: please explain your changes